# Sending keystrokes to a program

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys, keystroke

In window form, I made a button and I'm trying to make it send <kbd>F1</kbd> to a specific window (Such as FireFox, My Computer, etc...)

My questions are :

- How do I do it by the window's name? (such as "Mozilla Firefox")
- How do I do it by the process's name? (such as firefox.exe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By Window name:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  
[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr ptrFF = FindWindow(null, "Mozilla Firefox");
SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");
```

By Process name:

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0];
IntPtr ptrFF = proc.Handle;
SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
SendKeys.SendWait("{F1}");
```

Comment: @Or Betzalel - Updated with process name.

Comment: For community documentation purposes. From my experience "IntPtr ptrFF = proc.Handle;" will not grab the right handle. You should be using proc.MainWindowHandle instead. Ensure this is correct by using Spy++

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class.