# Changing the Window Focus c# user32.dll (SetForegroundWindow)

Tags: c#, windows, process, handle, user32

oh i have been trying to make a program which looks to see if a program in this case chrome is running then switching to it, i have been trying to follow a similar thread ([thread one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744111/sending-keystrokes-to-a-program), [thread two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667001/using-user32-dll-sendmessage-to-send-keys-with-alt-modifier)) unfortunately I'm having issues with the handle as it seems to like switching to windows explorer (file manager)

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  
[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr ptrFF = FindWindow(null, "chrome");
SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
```

---

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")[0];
IntPtr ptrFF = proc.Handle;
SetForegroundWindow(ptrFF);
```

these are the two bits of code i have been playing with, however i only got the second one to actuly do somthing, using a basic console aplication i tested weather it was actuly finding the right prosess when i uses "chrome" as the name and this appeared to be the case
test code:

```
   var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0];
   Console.WriteLine(proc.ToString());
```

The Output of the Writeline is "System.Diagnostics.Prosess (chrome)"
if i printed Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0].Handle;
it comes out as 572

but using:

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0].Handle;
Console.WriteLine(proc.ToString());
SetForegroundWindow(proc);
```

doesn't set the current window to chrome nor give me any errors

Comment: Try using `MainWindowHandle` instead of `Handle`?

Comment: that doesnt work eather, the handle returns 0

`var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0].MainWindowHandle;                                           Console.WriteLine(proc.ToString());`

Comment: It is *definitely* not going to work if you use a process id where a window handle is required.  SetForegroundWindow() just isn't guaranteed to work at all, you cannot shove a window into the user's face.  There's a dirty trick around it, also available in the .NET framework.  Use the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate() method.  It takes the process id.

Comment: ok.. so as the rest of my program is written in c# what do i do?

Comment: so . handle isnt the window handle? its the id... so whats .Id?

Comment: i found this, unfortnatly i cant quite make heads or tails of it, is it gunna work? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?356070-ShowWindow-can-t-bring-to-front-Resolved-D&highlight=activate